# Is it possible, with `sed` or otherwise, to apply a regex transform to an input stream that may not contain newlines?

Tags: shell, sed

I have a shell pipeline that contains a sed expression:

```
source | sed -e 's:xxxxx:yyyyy:g' | sink
```

It works but it has a latent flaw because `sed` works on whole lines. This means that the `sink` will see nothing until the `source` sends a newline. It becomes a problem if the source never sends a newline.

The shell is `bash` but I hope that isn't relevant. The strings `xxxxx` and `yyyyy` could be any regex and may use capture groups, to copy some `x` to `y`.

**Is it possible, with `sed` or otherwise, to apply a regex transform to an input stream that may not contain newlines ?**

I have solved the problem by writing a filter in Ruby but I wonder if existing tools can be used instead of writing code.

Comment: It's possible, but not a good idea - regular expression processing time increases exponentially as the string length grows. Can you not break the stream on some delimiter first with `tr`, then perform the edits, and `tr` the `\n`ewlines back to whatever they were before?

Comment: Perhaps that's the answer. The delimiter would be `<n>` where `n` is a number and it's surrounded by angle-brackets `<` and `>`. A newline needs to be inseted before the delimiter, which needs to be retained. Can `tr` do this?

Comment: re the string length growing, I need to do this in a pipe between two other processes. The string in the filter should not get long as it should not unnecessarily buffer. My attempt in Ruby only buffers after a `<` and then only while a regex matches `<\n*`...

Comment: No. That's the only proven delimiter you have? A possible way to get around that is with `dd cbs="$NEW_LINE_LENGTH" conv=unblock` - but that will not only split out intput to certain line lengths, it will also strip away any trailing spaces which might be found at the break point.

Comment: Is the source plain ascii or random binary data? Does the source protocol tell you where those `s:x:y:g` are going to show up? I recently had this issue with multipart/form-data. I made it work with `sed` but it was so ugly and slow that in the end, I used a parser written in C.

Comment: It's syslog ascii text from a router with rubbish firmware that can only blast the entire log on demand to a broadcast address and it does so in one large unstructured blob. I drew the same conclusion and wrote a parser in 15 lines of ruby. It meets the objective but I'd hoped there may be a better way.

Comment: Oh - syslog? so compressing spaces wouldn't matter, right? There shouldn't be any legitimate reason for any of that to contain sequences of blanks that matter, right? In such a case `dd` really will be your friend.

Comment: Why does source need to send newlines at all? `echo -n "fooxxxxxbarxxxxx" |sed -e 's:xxxxx:yyyyy:g'` works just fine and no newlines were outputted.

Comment: @PSkocik - well, sure, but there's a limit to that. Processing regular expressions at speed does not work very well at all when you do it on strings of inordinate length - especially if back-references are involved. Also, `sed` - and most others - tend to buffer input by line. And so if there are none of those - and if processing works at all - you don't get put out a regular out stream and instead have to swallow - and afterward print - it all at once.

Comment: @PSkocik - that works because there is an EOF at the end of the string and that causes `sed` to flush its buffer. That doesn't apply to a continuous stream.

Comment: PSkocik actually I stand corrected by @Gilles. Sed (at least my GNU v4.2.2) does not output the last line if it hasn't got a newline terminator.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually, thinking about it, you can first affect *all* possibles:

```
source |
tr '\n<' '<\n'  |
paste -sd\\n - -|
sed  -e'/^[0-9]\{1,\}>/!{$!H;1h;$!d'\
     -e\} -e'x;y/\n</<\n/;s//<&/'   \
     -ew\ /dev/fd/1 |
filter ... | sink
```

That will break your in-stream by first *un*conditionally swapping all `<` for `\n` and afterward *conditionally* swapping them back appropriately. This is necessary because the delimiter you mention is *not* a single character *(as a newline is)* and so a simple translation is not enough to guarantee your edit context unless you *first* delimit your stream. In other words, the edits you mention might that be required - such as capture groups and other context-sensitive matches which are understood to apply to a *record* - cannot be made reliably until you've verified your end-points.

---

#### unbuffered

---

`sed` only buffers up to the first occurrence in input of the regular expression match *`<[0-9]+>`* by first translating all *`<`* to `\n`ewlines and vice versa, and then stacking input by line in `sed`'s `H`old space until *`^[0-9]\{1,\}>`* is matched.

But `tr` and `paste` do block buffer output when writing to pipes - 4kb blocks or more.

Two more versions which handle that:

```sh
sol1(){
    {   cat; printf '\n\4\n'; } |
    {   dd obs=1 cbs=512 conv=sync,unblock \
        <"$(pts;stty eol \";cat <&3 >&4&)" 
    }   3<&0 <&- <>/dev/ptmx 2>/dev/null 4>&0 |
    sed  -ne'/<[0-9]\{1,\}>/!{H;$!d' -e\} \
          -e'x;s/\n//g;w /dev/fd/1'
}
```

That pushes all input to a pty and sets `dd` up to read from it. It uses that little C program from your other question - `pts` - to unlock and assign `dd` the fd. In the above case it is the kernel which does the delimiting. The pty line discipline is configured with `"` as the `stty` *`eol`* char - which doesn't get removed from output as the *`eof`* char does but does push the pty buffer to `dd` for each occurrence and satisfies its *`read()`*. For every one of `dd`'s *`read()`s* it first pads the tail-end of its out-buffer to 512 chars with spaces and then squeezes any/all trailing spaces to a single newline.

Here's a modified version of same which could solve the last line being held back problem:

```
sol1_5(){
    {   cat; printf '\n\4\n'; } |
    {   dd ibs=16k obs=2 cbs=4k conv=sync,unblock <"$(pts
        stty raw isig quit \^- susp \^- min 1 time 2
        cat  <&3 >&4&)" 
    }   3<&0 <&- <>/dev/ptmx 2>/dev/null 4>&0 |
    sed -ne's/<[0-9]\{1,\}>/\n&/g;/./w /dev/fd/1'
}
```

Here's another, altogether different version which unbuffers `tr` and `paste`:

```sh
sol2(){
    stdbuf -o0 tr '\n<' '<\n'  |
    stdbuf -o0 paste -sd\\n - -|
    sed  -ue'/^[0-9]\{1,\}>/!{$!H;1h;$!d'\
         -e\} -e'x;y/\n</<\n/;s//<&/'
}
```

I tested both methods with your sample data:

```
for sol in 1 2
do  printf '<37> Jul 28 10:40:47 127.0.0.1 time="2015-07-28 10:40:47" msg="LOGOUT User admin logged out on TELNET (10.0.200.1)"<37> Jul 28 10:45:58 127.0.0.1 time="2015-07-28 10:45:58" msg="LOGIN User admin logged in on TELNET (10.0.200.1)"<37> Jul 28 10:40:47 127.0.0.1 time="2015-07-28 10:40:47" msg="LOGOUT User admin logged out on TELNET (10.0.200.1)"<37> Jul 28 10:45:58 127.0.0.1 time="2015-07-28 10:45:58" msg="LOGIN User admin logged in on TELNET (10.0.200.1)"' |
   cat - /dev/tty | "sol$sol" | cat
```

In both cases the first three lines printed immediately, but the fourth was held back in the buffer - because `sed` doesn't print a buffer until it finds the beginning of the next, and so it remains one line behind input until EOF. Pressing *`CTRL+D`* got it printed.

---

```
<37> Jul 28 10:40:47 127.0.0.1 time="2015-07-28 10:40:47" msg="LOGOUT User admin logged out on TELNET (10.0.200.1)"
<37> Jul 28 10:45:58 127.0.0.1 time="2015-07-28 10:45:58" msg="LOGIN User admin logged in on TELNET (10.0.200.1)"
<37> Jul 28 10:40:47 127.0.0.1 time="2015-07-28 10:40:47" msg="LOGOUT User admin logged out on TELNET (10.0.200.1)"
<37> Jul 28 10:45:58 127.0.0.1 time="2015-07-28 10:45:58" msg="LOGIN User admin logged in on TELNET (10.0.200.1)"
```

But `sol1_5` uses another method altogether - it doesn't rely on character context to delimit input, but instead trusts that each `write()` of 4k or fewer bytes must represent at least 1 full context and so it prepends newlines within each as it thinks appropriate and immediately flushes output.

It works by setting the `stty` *`min`* and *`time`* values for `dd`'s pty. If you set *`min > 0` **and** `time > 0`* on a non-canonical terminal device that terminal will block a read until it receives at least *`min`* chars and afterward continue to block until *`time`* tenths of a second have passed. In that way if you can rely on each *`write()`* to the terminal being so many bytes and completing in so much time - and I think 4k and .2 secs pretty fair assumptions for a log write, personally - then you can read input and flush output *synchronously*.

And so `sol1_5` printed all 4 lines immediately.

---

#### the sed script

---

It's actually a very simple methodology, and can probably be adapted fairly universally to handle multiple character delimiters with `sed` - which by default only delimits records on a single character - the newline.

1. Transform all occurences of the first char in the delimiter pattern to a newline and any occurring newlines to that char.

   - Part of the the noted complication below: ensure you've got newlines at the end of your stream.
   - `tr '\n<' '<\n' | paste -sd\\n - -`
2. Scan the newly newline-delimited input for the rest of your delimiter pattern - but only for occurrences at the head of a line.

   - Besides being easy, this is also very efficient. You only have to check the first few chars for any input line. `sed` barely has to work at all.
   - `/^[0-9]\{1,\}>/`
3. Append to `H`old space a copy of any line which does `!` not match and `d`elete it, but for those that do, e`x`change edit and hold buffers so your current pattern space is all of the last fully delimited record and hold space contains only the very first part of the next delimited sequence.

   - The most complicated bit is that you need to take care on the first and last input lines. The complication here stems from `sed`'s basic efficiency - you can truly work a single record per buffer.
   - You don't want to stick in an extra `\n`ewline for no reason on the first line so you should overwrite `h`old space rather than appending to `H`old space in that case.
   - And you should both `!` *not* `H`old or `d`elete the `$` last line  because it's empty, but your hold buffer isn't. There is no more input to scan, but you still need to handle your last held record.
   - `/.../!{$!H;1h;$!d;};x`
4. Rather than applying an expensive `s///`ubstitution regexp to restore your now fully-delimited context, you can instead use `sed`'s own `y///` transliteration function to more efficiently and at one time swap all of your saved intervening `\n`ewline characters for your delimiter's first character.

   - `y/\n</<\n/`
5. Last you just need to insert a single new `<` at the head of pattern space - because the `\n`ewline you need inserted was already added at the end of the last buffer cycle when it was printed.

   - The most efficient way to do this is simply to reuse the `//` same regexp you've been testing your input lines with all along. In this way `sed` can get away with only needing to *`regcomp()`* compile a single regular expression and repeatedly *`regexec()`* execute the same automaton repeatedly to delimit the entire in-stream reliably.
   - `s//<&/`

You should be able to process that out-stream as a regular, `\n`ewline delimited text file now.

#### test

```sh
printf '%s\n' the string \
              "<9>more $(printf %050s|tr ' ' '<') string" \
              and \<9\> "<more<string and <9> more<string" |
tr '<\n' '\n<'   |
paste -sd\\n - - |
sed  -e'/^[0-9]\{1,\}>/!{$!H;1h;$!d' \
     -e\} -e'x;y/\n</<\n/;s//<&/'
```

---

```
the
string

<9>more <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<< string
and

<9>
<more<string and 
<9> more<string
```

Now if your goal is to apply your edit to a string which might be described like *`^<[0-9]+>(^(<[0-9]+>))*`* then at this point you probably don't even need a second filter - because that's exactly what `sed`'s pattern space represents just before it prints it out at the end of the little script there - `\n`ewlines and all.

Using a modified version of my previous example again...

#### string>data

```sh
printf '%s\n' the string \
              "<1>more $(printf %050s|tr ' ' '<') string" \
              and \<2\> "<more<string and <3> more<string" |
tr '<\n' '\n<'   |
paste -sd\\n - - |
sed  -e'/^[0-9]\{1,\}>/!{$!H;1h;$!d' \
     -e\} -e'x;y/\n</<\n/;s//<&/'  \
     -e'/^<[2-9][0-9]*>/s/string/data/g'
```

---

```
the
string

<1>more <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<< string
and

<2>
<more<data and 
<3> more<data
```

Comment: Certainly an interesting approach but I couldn't get it to work with my input data and I couldn't get your input data to work across a socat pipe. I think the expression is probably too complex to be usable in a real scenario. I think, in this case, my small ruby script is probably the most realistic solution. That said, I think this is a novel approach to the problem.

Comment: @starfry - I broke it. I'll fix it,

Comment: @starfry - fixed. But really it's a 2-line filter. Just do me a favor - do some tests on input of real size, and compare your completion times between the `sed` and the ruby stuff. But don't accept the answer if you use yours - in that case accept your answer - you can totally do that and *should* for the benefit of those that come after to read this.

Comment: @starfry - by the way, to get `sed` to explicitly flush output per record just add the third line like: `-e's/xxxx/yyyy/gw /dev/fd/1' -ed` and `sed` will do a *`write()`* every time you print.

Comment: See [this sample data](http://pastebin.com/vnuW26rv) and my [notes](http://pastebin.com/E5LrmQCq). It does work with an input file but not for some reason across a socat pipe. I think am going to go with my ruby answer on this one. I will do some timings for you  though, I just need to collect some data first.

Comment: @starfry - oh yeah! - that's `tr` and `paste` doing that. So maybe Danny's answer was more relevant than I thought! Those programs will buffer output at 4k a block at least. Both of those will happily line-buffer if you set it up `stdbuf`, though. Or I could do a `dd` version portably after all - looking at your data gives me a pretty solid conviction of that.

Comment: @starfry - I wrote two example unbuffered solutions and put them in - one a home-brew and the other `stdbuf`.

Comment: I thought your `sol2` was the way to go for a second there, but it still buffers the end of line as you said in your answer. I have some timings for you (input yields 93 lines after processing): your original solution: real0.008s user0s sys0.003s; `sol1`: r0.022s u0.003s s  0.020s; `sol2`: r0.026s u0.003s s0.003s `sol2`: 0.022s and my Ruby script: r0.045s u0.033s s0.010s.

Comment: @starfry - the buffer is always one line behind - it needs to find the next match before it can be sure it's delimited the whole segment. How do you do it w/ Ruby? It is careful in its workings - it could be more simple if I just looked for `<$` - and in that case it could print sooner - but if it did then it might erroneously print a line-break if `<` could occur anywhere else.

Comment: just noticed I have the same issue. I'm looking to see if I can fix it...

Comment: @starfry - because the pattern you look for is part of the *next* output line, the only way I can imagine you could do it would involve assuming the `<` means you need to print a `\n`ewline in all cases - and doing so - but also incorporating some logic to check after the fact and then recursively editing your output file. Such a thing would not be possible with a single `sed` pipeline as far as I know - though I can imagine I could do it with a backgrounded `sed` monitoring another `sed`'s outfile. Maybe it is doable w/ Ruby - if you figure it out let me know, yeah?

Comment: Well it isn't my Ruby program. I've done some tests and the downstream pipe (`systemd-cat` in my case) buffers until it gets a newline. If I just run the pipe into my Ruby program from a terminal than I get all the output immediately. To my Ruby program the input is one long line. I wonder if I could detect the stream blocking and send a newline if the last character wasn't...

Comment: @starfry - your Ruby writes output by byte? You might want to switch it line-buffered output - it would probably increase its efficiency a good deal - especially if your sync is buffering input by line *(which is pretty common)*. Why do you need it so soon as all that anyway? Another solution could be a tiny time loop - you  could hold off 1 second after reading the last input byte  and if no more input is received in that amount of time flush an empty out-line.

Comment: @starfry - I wrote a little time loop version - while it does present an altogether different set of problems *(like possibly splitting an input line if a single input read is greater than 4k)* - it doesn't withhold the last line.

Comment: the `sol1_5` works well. I have just modified my Ruby script to insert a newline if it blocks. Again, probably not the best code in the world but it works and the data stream isn't so great that writing a character at a time really bothers me. One difference I note is that my code passes anything through, inserting newlines before any delimiters in the stream, whereas yours drops lines without delimiters. Not a major issue as the stream is compliant with that but a minor difference nonetheless

Comment: @starfry - I saw that. I can't upvote it again though. The `sed` could be `sed 's/.../.../g;/./w /dev/fd/1'` to not drop lines without delimiters, though. And it probably should be. In that case it wouldn't insert a newline before every `<` thing, but it would drop *empty* lines.

Answer (score 1):

When a program writes to a terminal the buffer is flushed on every newline, but you can use the program **unbuffer**  (Note in some distributions the command is stdbuf )

Try something like this

```
unbuffer source | sed -e 's:xxxxx:yyyyy:g' | sink
```

Comment: I don't understand how this is relevant...?

Comment: I think I get it now!

Answer (score 1):

At least GNU sed handles input that doesn't have a newline at the end (and it produces output without a final newline if the last incomplete line is passed through). A text file under Unix must by definition end with a newline if it isn't empty, and sed is a text utility, so this leniency to non-text input is not guaranteed.

Since sed is designed to transform lines, I'd expect most implementations to read the whole input line into memory before applying any transformation, and in particular before producing any output corresponding to that input line.

If you want to process that input conveniently with sed, pick a character that isn't matched by the `xxxxx` pattern or produced by the `yyyyy` replacement text, but appears reasonably often in the input. Translate it to a newline, and vice versa after the call to sed.

```
 source | tr ':\n' '\n:' | sed -e 's:foo:bar:g' | tr ':\n' '\n:' | sink
```

If the're no good character to pick, sed is probably not going to help you here, and ruby is a reasonable choice.

Comment: I dont think this is correct: _A text file under Unix must by definition end with a newline if it isn't empty_. The command `echo -n "abc" > file` produces a file containing 3 characters but no newline. The other thing that triggers `sed` is receipt of an `EOF`. In the absence of either it will buffer indefinitely. My Q refers to an ongoing stream rather than a file, so EOF won't happen either (well, not until the source is terminated).

Comment: @starfry The command `echo -n "abc" > file` does not produce a text file. It produces a file which contains only printable characters, but which is not a text file. Traditional Unix utilities tended to skip the last incomplete line of files that didn't end with a newline, so for example `sed 's/a/b/' file` would print nothing. GNU utilities do process the last incomplete line, so it prints `bbc` in this case.

Comment: That's interesting. On my GNU sed 4.2.2, if I do `echo -n "abc" > file ; sed 's/a/b/' file` I get nothing - I never knew that! If I remove the `-n` I get `bbc` as you say. But we're digressing from the original question. Can you link to the definition of a text file ?

Comment: @starfry My sed says it's gnu, version 4.2.2 as well and the example does work on my Linux Mint 17. It continues to work even if I add the --posix flag to sed.

Comment: @PSkocik you're right. it does work with `-n`. My prompt clears the current line before displaying and that hid it.

Answer (score 1):

I implemented a small script in Ruby to solve this problem. It's used like this:

```
source | myscript.rb | sink
```

Here's the source

```
$stdout.sync                                   # no outbound buffering by Ruby
buf=''
$stdin.each_char do |c|
  if buf.length>0 || c=='<'                    # buffering starts when '<' received
    buf << c                                   #        and continues until flushed
    buf.gsub!(/(<\d+>)/,"\n\\1") if (c == '>') # regex transform matching buffer
    unless (buf =~ /<\d*$/)                    # flush buffer when regex fails
      STDOUT << buf
      buf.replace ''                           # empty buffer stops buffering
    end
  else
    STDOUT << c;                               # unbuffered output
  end
  $stdout.flush                                # no buffering, please!
end
```

A ruby expert might improve on that but it's a quick 'n' dirty hack that solves the problem for me.

Basically, it reads stdin one character at a time and checks it for the first match character, the `<`. If not found it writes it immediately to stdout. If it did match, it instead writes to a buffer and then continues to do so unless the buffer contents fail a regex match for a valid delimiter (`<` followed by zero or more digits), in which case it flushes the buffer and buffering stops. If, while buffering, it gets a `>` then it performs the transformation by regex.

**Update**

The above script works but downstream processes may buffer their input if they wait for a newline. This means the last line of input can get held up in the downstream pipeline. The version below uses a non-blocking read and inserts a newline if the input would block:

```
STDOUT.sync                                   # no outbound buffering by Ruby
buf=''
def read_from_stdin()
  last=''
  while true
    begin
      c = STDIN.read_nonblock(1)              # read 1 character; don't block
    rescue Errno::EWOULDBLOCK                 # exception if nothing to read
      yield "\n" unless last=="\n"            # send a newline if prior character wasn't
      IO.select([STDIN])                      # block (wait for input)
      retry                                   # go back to 'begin' again
    end 
    yield last=c                              # remember and send read character
  end 
end

read_from_stdin do |c| 
  if buf.length>0 || c=='<'                    # buffering starts when '<' received
    buf << c                                   #        and continues until flushed
    buf.gsub!(/(<\d+>)/,"\n\\1") if (c == '>') # regex transform matching buffer
    unless (buf =~ /<\d*$/)                    # flush buffer when regex fails
      STDOUT << buf 
      buf.replace ''                           # empty buffer stops buffering
    end 
  else
    STDOUT << c;                               # unbuffered output
  end 
  STDOUT.flush                                 # no buffering, please!
end
```